# struts2-convention and struts2-config-browser-plugin cannot work if i change struts.xml path

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin, struts2-config-browser

I use struts2-convention-plugin and struts2-config-browser-plugin in struts2, if i change the default struts.xml path in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts/struts.xml</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
 </filter>
```

they cannot work anymore, why?

Answer (score 0):

`struts/struts.xml` is used to locate the Struts configuration file, but it cannot open it because it doesn't exist. Use `struts.xml` instead and put it onto classpath.

Comment: I change classpath struts.xml to struts/struts.xml, so it exists.

Comment: @TardisXu the filename is wrong, it should be a correct file name, not a file path or protocol.

Comment: If you can't use struts2-convention-plugin don't do it, if you can then do what I said to you.